# reference number and instruction of a spaceship

Tags: instructions, vehicle

I have only an image of that spaceship, (and all briks of course) but I don't know its serial number which makes me hard to find instructions to rebuild it. 
The image of the spaceship is this one, anybody can help me to rebuild it?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This set is [6848 Strategic Pursuer](http://peeron.com/inv/sets/6848-1).

[image: 6848]

Instruction scans are [available on Peeron](http://peeron.com/scans/6848-1/).

Comment: It was exactly what I need! I build it! Thank you!